# How to programmatically create a subproject in root gradle.build file

Tags: java, gradle

I have a project with a number of submodules, so a structure that looks something like this:

```
\root
  \otherfiles
  \modules
    \moduleA
       \src\main\java... etc
    \moduleB
build.gradle
settings.gradle
```

I want to keep everything in the root build.gradle and define the projects in-line. It seems this should be possible, but I just can't figure out the right magic incantations to make it happen.

I've tried this (along with several variations) in the root build.gradle :-

```
repositories {
   ...
}

dependencies {
   ...
}

project('common') {        
   projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "modules/moduleA")
   apply plugin: 'java'
}
```

But Gradle just says project path could not be found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind... by poking around in the Hibernate gradle files, I found that if I add this to the root *settings.gradle*:

```
include 'common'
project(':common').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, "modules/common")
```

Then I can refer to the subproject definition in the root *build.gradle* file like this:

```
project('common'){
    apply plugin: 'java'

    dependencies {
        ....
    }
}
```